# Does only one Thread executing a Kernel implement the declaration of an array in Shared Memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I am implementing the following CUDA kernel that stores an array in Shared Memory:

```
// Difference between adjacent array elements
__global__ void kernel( int* in, int* out )  {
   int i  = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

   // Allocate a shared array, one element per thread
   __shared__ int sh_arr[BOCK_SIZE];

   // each thread reads one element to sh_arr
   sh_arr[i] = in[i];

   // Ensure reads from all Threads in Block complete before continuing
   __syncthreads();
   if( i > 0 )
      out[i] = sh_arr[i] - sh_arr[i-1];
   // Ensure writes from all Threads in Block complete before continuing
   __syncthreads(); 
}
```

BLOCK_SIZE is a constant declared outside the kernel.

It seems like every Thread that executes this Kernel will create a new array because every Thread that executes this Kernel will see this line:

```
__shared__ int sh_arr[BOCK_SIZE];
```

Is it the case that only the first Thread that executes this Kernel will "see" this line, and all subsequent kernels overlook this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared variables in CUDA are shared between threads in the same block. I don't know exactly how it is done under the hood but threads in the same thread-block will see `__shared__ int sh_arr[BOCK_SIZE];` however, since it has the `__shared__` modifier, only one thread will create the array while the others will just use it.